# How to create a new .txt file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new .txt file in python by the following method if the file does not already exists:

```
company_name_file = open(company_name_file.txt, "r")

company_name_file.close()
```

But, it is not creating a new file if the file name does not exists. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: it is showing the following error message: NameError: name 'company_name_file' is not defined

Comment: You need to wrap the filename in quotes, to make it a string: `"company_name_file.txt"`.

Comment: @GinoMempin Got it thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open file: "NameError: name <filename> is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908067/cant-open-file-nameerror-name-filename-is-not-defined)

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question. Also, you should *always* include the error message in the question, as it could make it easier/clearer for people to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the "r" to a "w+".
`r` represents the read mode and `w` represents the write mode
Currently, your code is trying to read a file rather than write a file.

```
with open("company_name_file.txt", "w+") as company_name_file:
    company_name_file.write("Test")
```

Comment: I changed my code as you can see above, but it still showing an error

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7, share your snippet if you can!

Comment: Now its fine, earlier the name of the file was not in double quotation marks

Comment: Yep my bad. Corrected. The filename needs to be a string. 
As an FYI, the "with" keyword is useful for doing cleanup operations automatically (in this case closing the file). See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for